# the warnings turned into errors when an other error occurs

Tags: maven, hudson

I work on a maven (maven : V_3_0_4, java : V_1_7_0_03_64b) project with several sub-projects. I work also with the continuous integration server hudson.

Some of my sub-projects use the api `Signal` from `sun.misc.Signal` which is flagged with a WARNING during the compilation as `Signal is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release`. I do not discuss this point.

I witnessed something strange, after a commit from my development space, the hudson compilation triggered and failed with some magnificent traces :

```
[ERROR] toto.java[42,42] : Signal is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
```

I was a little bit lost since the configuration of the hudson did not change. An other strange sign was that those errors appeared on one sub-project but not on the others also using the api `Signal` where there was only the WARNING.

After some inquiries with the co-workers we found that the error was somewhere else (this was one of my mistake here : focusing on the pseudo errors from `Signal`) and after fixing it the warnings were back and the errors on `Signal` disappeared.

Is it standard to witness this "change state" of the flags ? Or is it specific to proprietary API : i.e. hudson detect the error and put the proprietary API warnings to errors since it could be related ? In short what happened here ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same kind of errors which were warnings previously.

```
[ERROR] <deleted>.java:[6,15] Unsafe is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
```

When I found out a problem at another code piece and fix it, those ones were also resolved. But I recommend you to do `mvn clean install` on Terminal instead of building from IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your case but what worked for me is to use an older version parent POM in the project POM file. The problem was I was using my own aggregated POM, which pointed to the newest version of company's parent POM, which pointed to JDK 1.7 in it. After reverting to an older version POM, which uses JDK 1.6, the error was gone.

I suppose what used to be at warning level in 1.6 changed to error level in 1.7.